# Why entity id is incremented after merging? [Grails]

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I want to create a generic code for updating entities. Here's what I come up with:

```
def update(id, Object updatedEntity) {
    def entity = findById(id)
    if (entity) {
        updatedEntity.id = id
        def mergedEntity = updatedEntity.merge()
        if (mergedEntity) {
            return mergedEntity
        } else {
            throw new ValidationException("Cannot update.", mergedEntity.errors)
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No ${domainClass.getSimpleName()} with id=${id} found.")
    }
}
```

Why `mergedEntity` always have incremented `id` value (I mean if `updatedEntity.id = 1`, then `mergedEntity.id` will be 2. And how can I fix it?

Comment: Is updatedEntity a detached entity?  I think you need to read up on what merge is actually used for.  http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html

Comment: Grails is a dynamic language and already has lots of built-in 'generic code' for handling things like this.  Could you explain what your trying to do and why?

Comment: @Gregg: yes, updatedEntity is detached.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee: I have lot's of entity types. And for all of them I need service-classes with basic CRUD and something more. I want to move as much common logic as possible to a parent service class (GenericService). Children classes will just create an entity from parameters, and pass it to correspondent parent method. Let's consider `UserService#update()`. It's code should be like this: `def updatedUser = new User(name: params.newName, age: params.newAge); super.update(params.id, updatedUser)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what caused the described behavior: my `id` parameter is always an instance of String, so when I pass id = 1, the actual id value is "1" and it's not treated as a hibernate `id`.

Besides this, to make this work I had to override `version` property as well.